# Flutter DateFormat.d() get all days

Tags: flutter, dart, date-formatting

I want to get all days respectively with `DateFormat.d()`. But `f.add()` gives an error. I guess because one is of type DateTime and the other is because it is String. How can i solve this?

My Code:

```
  final f = new DateFormat.d().format(DateTime.now());
  List data = List.generate(20, (index) => f.add(Duration(days: index)));
```

My Widget:

```
Swiper imageSlider(context) {
  var weekDays = {'1':'Mon','2':'Tue','3':'Wed','4':'Thu','5':'Fri'};
  final f = new DateFormat.d().format(DateTime.now());
  List data = List.generate(20, (index) => f.add(Duration(days: index)));
  int _index = 0;
  
  return Swiper(
    viewportFraction: .2,
    fade: -0.4,
    indicatorLayout: PageIndicatorLayout.SCALE,
    autoplay: false,
    onIndexChanged: (value) {
      _index = value;
    },
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    
      return Column(
        children: [
            Container(
              height: 40,
              width: 75,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            Text('Day number'),
            Text('Day name')
      ]);
    }, 
    
    itemCount: weekDays.length);
}
```

Comment: Your guess is right. Generate the ```DateTime``` list first then  format it.

Comment: Did you mean like this? `List<DateTime> data = List.generate(20, (index) => f.add(Duration(days: index)));` @LộcTrần

Comment: Yes. And if you want generate the list and format it in one line: ```List<String> data = List.generate(20, (index) => DateFormat.d().format(DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: index))));```